# ERROR on WAMP: allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.. virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, apache, iis, wamp

I have an ASP.NET C# website program which runs perfectly  when run in VS2010 but when I put it in the WWW/ASP folder of WAMP. It errors this message:

It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.

This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS

> Source File: C:\wamp\www\ASP\reportertest2\web.config    Line: 22

I tried removing the

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>



<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

I tried removing that code above in web.config but still the same error. I have tried using other solutions but I think they run it in VS2010, not on the WAMP server with aspdotnet_module. TAKE NOTE im using WIN7 so i dont have that IIS thing, I dont even know what it is.
Some posts said that try removing the second web.config (I have mine in the Accounts folder) . But still same error. Again when run in VS2010 it works fine, but when put in a server, it errors.

Comment: Probably a silly question, but is `reportest2` set up as an application, or just a virtual directory?

Comment: @Tim reportertest2 is the Website name when I created it in VS, then i just copy pasted it in the WWW/ASP folder. Sorry I dont know what you meant by the virtual dir and application. Thanks

Comment: Open IIS, find the folder `reportest2` - if it's not an application, you should be able to right-click on it, select "Convert to Application" and follow the wizard steps.  Just copying the folder over won't do it.

Comment: Dear sir @Tim i think i dont have IIS, because I have typed it i START and nothing shows, and I am using Windows 7. Could you guide me where to find it? PS: I have another single aspx file in the WWW/ASP folder. It works fine. it is the sample program needed to test the aspdotnet_module in the guides in the internet :) and the name is `reporterTest2` :D

Comment: Ooops...my bad.  I saw the C:\WAMP\www and my mind inserted C:\Inetpub\wwwroot.  You may not have IIS installed, so I'm not sure what to tell you. Sorry :(

Comment: waaaaaa. please help me :( this is a requirement in my OJT, none of the other workers use asp.net  because they let me choose my own language for that small report generator programm :(

Maybe there are other troubleshooting options? :(

Comment: Take a look at this link:  http://adamzwakk.com/how-to-install-asp-net-on-an-apache-2-0-x-wamp-server/

Comment: well thats the tutorial i followed to make their sample file work. it is named simple.aspx isnt it? I think the blog doesnt have enough info for mine :( huhu.. Do you know other genius people here? I dont know how to contact them, i dont even have enough reputation to chat you